# pass variable to php form after submitting the form

Tags: php, forms, variables

I want to pass the variable from php page to another without using sessions.

here's SearchCustomer.php page which have the from

```
<form action="controllers/Customer.controller.php" method="post">
<label for="cellPhoneNo">cell phone number</label>
    <input type="text" name="cellPhoneNo" class="textField"/>
    <span id="cellphonePrefix"></span>

    <label for="telephone">telephone </label>
    <input type="text" name="telephone" class="textField"/>

    <input type="submit" name="searchCustomer" value="بحث"/>
```

in Customer.controller.php I search for customer and return a `$result`, I want to pass the variables defined in  Customer.controller.php to SearchCustomer.php page which the from is submitted from without using sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem: You want to perform the search in `Customer.controller.php` and immediately display the results in `SearchCustomer.php`, right?

Well, that smells like AJAX :)

Try this (using jQuery):

**SearchCustomer.php**

```
<form id="search_form" action="controllers/Customer.controller.php" method="post">
//...
</form>

<div id="output">
</div>

<script>
$('#search_form').submit(function() {
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $('#output').append('field one: ' + data[i].field1 + '<br />');
    }
  }, 'json');
  return false;
});
</script>
```

**Customer.controller.php**

```
<?php

$cellPhoneNo = $_POST['cellPhoneNo'];
//....

//perform the search, 
//fetch the assoc-array, e.g. $results 
echo json_encode($results);
```

The code is untested, but you get the idea ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with hidden input controls.

In Customer.controller.php:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='result' value='{$result}'>";
```

In SearchCustomer.php:

```
$passedResult = $_POST['result'];
```

**Update**: Question did change a bit, use a redirect similar to this:

```
header("Location: http://yoursite.com/SearchCustomer.php?result={$result}");
```

Comment: In Customer.controller.php I use header to redirect to SearchCustomer.php page, so I can't use echo before it!

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of hidden fields some way!

for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="multiPageValue" 
value="<?php echo $_POST['multiPageValue'];?>"/>
```

and you can go on using this snipped on all the consecutive pages to which you would be navigating by submitting form!

Comment: @Linus Kleen Well, the problem asked was not about XSS test, but a simple problem, of retaining values to multiple pages!, to test it specifically for XSS, he may choose his own way, as using `htmlspecialchars()` or whatever better strategy he uses! how awkward it would had been to show and example like `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['multiPageValue']);?>"/>`, thanks for your negative point, though it doesn't makes any sense to me! :)

Answer (score 2):

Once a user submits your form, your server will handle the form data  sent to it. PHP takes that and parses it for you in an array named $_POST.

[PHP $_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Since you do not define an action in your form, the _POST array will be available to the same page as your form once its submitted. Do a simple test at the top of your page:

```
if(isset($_POST['cellPhoneNo'])) {
 echo "Thank you for your phone numbers!";
}
```